# Joining instead of Cutting with BoolTool Ctrl Shift - Shortcut

Tags: add-on, edit-mode, 3d-printing, stl

I have been using Blender to edit STL files for resin 3d Printing.

I have an object that I want to cut and I create the shape I want to cut out of it, but when I give the <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>-</kbd> command, the two objects are joined.

I select the cutting shape, hold <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and select the part to be cut, then give the <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> command, and about 50% of the time it will join the items. The other 50% it will cut the way I want it to.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Boolean modifier in Properties > Modifier Properties > Add Modifier > Boolean, and choose the object you want to cut with, in the menu for Object. I'm not sure what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> shortcut does.

[image: cube]

Answer (score 0):

In *bool tools*, there is another shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> for union operation or u can use the Object Menu.

> 1] The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> method
>
> [image: Bool Tools 'Ctr Shift +']
>
> > Here is the *wireframe*
>
> [image: Wire Frame]
>
> > And here is the **mesh** in *x-ray* mode, as you can see there are no *redundant faces*.
>
> [image: Mesh]

> 2] **The Object Menu**, u can access *all* the bool tool
> **operations** from the *object menu*.
>
> > Sorry For the long menu!
>
> [image: Object Menu]

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> to leave the modifier on the object.  Look at the options on the modifier and check to see if the Fast Solver cuts the object like you expect.